# De-duplicate Firefox bookmarks

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

What methods exist to de-duplicate Firefox bookmarks.

As I search Google I find that there previously was a plugin called [CheckPlaces](http://www.andyhalford.com/), but that no longer seems to exist.  Another popular suggestion seems to be [AM-DeadLink](http://www.aignes.com/deadlink.htm), which I tried, but it completely trashed my bookmarks.  (Fortunately I had a backup first, and yes I had closed Firefox first as instructed).

I was trying to move all my youtube.com bookmarks into a folder.  I tried doing a search, and then dragging the bookmarks into the folder.  Apparently this creates a copy, instead of moving them as I expected.  So now I have 3 of everything since I had tried a couple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be heavier than you want, but if you are using [XMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) or are open to using it, it has a [De-Duplicator](http://helpdesk.xmarks.com/troubleshooting/duplicate-bookmarks-2/) feature

Comment: Xmarks certainly looks good, but I have a pretty large set of bookmarks (30,000).  Any idea if Xmarks will be able to handle that without making a mess?  I had tried it in back in the past when it was `Foxmarks`, and it seemed to act all buggy.  (asked on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31940/xmarks-limitations)

Comment: You could always try using a portable version of Firefox or a new profile. No permanent harm and it might work in which case you could just export the bookmarks from there and import them to your real Firefox profile.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bookmark-duplicate-detector/ although at the time of posting it's not available for FireFox 15

Comment: There is apparently a development version for Firefox 13+ located over here: http://bookmarkdd.mozdev.org/installation.html

In any case, you could always just use a standalone (portable) version of an older Firefox version, install this extension, import your bookmarks, do your thing with the de-duplication, export your bookmarks and then just reimport the bookmarks in the normal Firefox installation.